# How to insert image to existing JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

Am trying to create login page for my application and i did it well but i couldn't able to add a image to my JFrame, here is my code for login page....

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

public class log extends JFrame {

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
       static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
       static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://sqldatabase.com/databasename";

       //  Database credentials
       static final String USER = "usernamr";
       static final String PASS = "pass";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        log frameTabel = new log();
    }

    JButton blogin = new JButton("Login");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    JTextField txuser = new JTextField(15);
    JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(15);

    log() throws IOException{
        super("Login Autentification");

        setSize(500,500);
        setLocation(300,280);
        panel.setLayout (null); 

        //ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image.jpeg");
        //JLabel hangman = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(urlOfImageFile));
        //panel.add(image, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("F:\\IModubytes\\Images\\1.jpg"));
        //JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        //panel.add(picLabel);
        //panel.repaint(); 

        txuser.setBounds(300,100,150,20);
        pass.setBounds(300,135,150,20);
        blogin.setBounds(380,170,80,20);

        panel.add(blogin);
        panel.add(txuser);
        panel.add(pass);

        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        actionlogin();
    }

    public void actionlogin(){
        blogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                Connection conn = null;
                   Statement stmt = null;
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                    stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    String puname = txuser.getText();
                    String ppaswd = pass.getText();
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM EmpDetails WHERE id="+puname;
                    System.out.println(puname);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                    String pw = null;
                    while(rs.next()) {
                        pw = rs.getString("pass");
                    }
                    rs.close();
                    //if(puname.equals("test") && ppaswd.equals(pw)) {
                    if(ppaswd.equals(pw)) {
                        newFrame regFace =new newFrame();
                        regFace.setVisible(true);
                        dispose();
                    } else {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
                        txuser.setText("");
                        pass.setText("");
                        txuser.requestFocus();
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me how to add image in this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the code to load the image and add the label to your frame.

So the next step is to add your components to the label and then add the label to the content pane, instead of adding the components to the panel and adding the panel to the content pane.

Also, don't use a null layout!!! Swing was designed to be used with layout mangers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: This is the first time am using panel and frame so can you please tell me how to do this....?

Comment: @RamkumarP, I edited my question to give a little more detail.

Comment: @RamkumarP, a small example of what? The tutorial already have small working examples.

Comment: You said that "So the next step is to add your components to the label and then add the label to the content pane, instead of adding the components to the panel and adding the panel to the content pane." for this only i requested for help...